# How to count data or entries in a html table?

Tags: html-table

I have a normal html table and I want to be able to count the number of entries or rows in the table. I've seen a lot of examples out there that use jQuery but they use the alert code for displaying the number. I just need a message above the table that would say 'there are # entries' or something that would update itself automatically with each new row.

I'm a new to all of this so it helps if you  can be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
var rows = $('tr').length;
```

Comment: Okay so since I'm a noob how would the format exactly be from the beginning and also i have more than one table in the same page.. so how would the formatting be exactly?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to write your code for you. Your best bet is to try to learn a little jQuery. It's that hard.